# Spring Integration with header-value-router router

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Message channel throws an exception while sending a message.Please help me, anyone.

Exception Caused by:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failed to resolve channel name 'ZCRMXIF_PRODUCT_MATERIAL'; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: 
    failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'ZCRMXIF_PRODUCT_MATERIAL' in the BeanFactory.; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'ZCRMXIF_PRODUCT_MATERIAL' is defined.
```

Code :

```
Map headers = Collections.singletonMap("IDOCTYP","ZCRMXIF_PRODUCT_MATERIAL");
idocXmlInboundChannel.send(new GenericMessage("message", headers));
```

Spring configuration

```
<int:channel id="idocXmlInboundChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter log-full-message="true" id="logger" level="DEBUG" />

<bean id="idocInboundService" class="com.hybris.datahub.sapidocintegration.spring.HttpInboundService">
    <property name="idocXmlInboundChannel" ref="idocXmlInboundChannel" />
</bean>

<!-- Data Hub input channel for raw data -->
<int:channel id="rawFragmentDataInputChannel" />

<!-- Maps received IDOCs by value of header attribute: "IDOCTYP" to corresponding mapping service -->
<int:header-value-router input-channel="idocXmlInboundChannel" header-name="IDOCTYP">
    <int:mapping value="ZCRMXIF_PRODUCT_MATERIAL" channel="ZCRMMATMAS" />
</int:header-value-router>

<!-- sap crm product -->
<int:service-activator input-channel="ZCRMMATMAS" output-channel="rawFragmentDataInputChannel" ref="customproductCRMMappingService" method="map" />

<!-- Dummy implementations of mapping services implemented elsewhere -->    
<bean id="customproductCRMMappingService" class="com.hybris.datahub.sapidocintegration.IDOCMappingService">
    <property name="rawFragmentDataExtensionSource" value="customproduct" />
    <property name="rawFragmentDataType" value="RawCustomProduct" />
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something wrong in your configuration or you don't show exactly that config which fails.

The `AbstractMappingMessageRouter` has the logic:

```
    // if the channelMappings contains a mapping, we'll use the mapped value
    // otherwise, the String-based channelKey itself will be used as the channel name
    String channelName = channelKey;
    boolean mapped = false;
    if (this.channelMappings.containsKey(channelKey)) {
        channelName = this.channelMappings.get(channelKey);
        mapped = true;
    }
    if (this.prefix != null) {
        channelName = this.prefix + channelName;
    }
    if (this.suffix != null) {
        channelName = channelName + this.suffix;
    }
    MessageChannel channel = resolveChannelForName(channelName, message);
    if (channel != null) {
        channels.add(channel);
        if (!mapped && !(this.dynamicChannels.get(channelName) != null)) {
            this.dynamicChannels.put(channelName, channel);
        }
    }
```

So we fallback to the normal `value` resolution only in case we dont't have a mapping for that value.

Surely you have it in your sample:

```
<int:mapping value="ZCRMXIF_PRODUCT_MATERIAL" channel="ZCRMMATMAS" />
```

So, that isn't clear what is wrong...

Maybe there is some incompatible symbol in the `value="ZCRMXIF_PRODUCT_MATERIAL"` and `singletonMap("IDOCTYP","ZCRMXIF_PRODUCT_MATERIAL")` header definition...